# How do I group a JSON array by a key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects that hold game data. Each object in the array has a date, location, game type, winner, and loser.

I want my output to be an array of objects with the attributes player, wins, and losses (i.e. the output will be grouped by player, whereas each object inside the array input has a winner player and a loser player). The output will tell me, out of all the games played, how many wins and losses each player has.

Comment: share the object

Comment: And the output format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your game data structure is as belows

```
const gameData = [{
  date: '12/02/2018',
  location: 'Germany',
  gameType: 'any',
  winner: 'Joe Smith',
  loser: 'Leo Messi',
}, {
  date: '20/02/2018',
  location: 'Australia',
  gameType: 'any',
  winner: 'Joe Smith',
  loser: 'Cristiano',
}, {
  date: '23/02/2018',
  location: 'England',
  gameType: 'any',
  winner: 'Alexi Sanchez',
  loser: 'Joe Smith',
}]
```

Then here is the possible solution.

```js
const gameData = [{
  date: '12/02/2018',
  location: 'Germany',
  gameType: 'any',
  winner: 'Joe Smith',
  loser: 'Leo Messi',
}, {
  date: '20/02/2018',
  location: 'Australia',
  gameType: 'any',
  winner: 'Joe Smith',
  loser: 'Cristiano',
}, {
  date: '23/02/2018',
  location: 'England',
  gameType: 'any',
  winner: 'Alexi Sanchez',
  loser: 'Joe Smith',
}]

const playerObjects = gameData.reduce((acc, game) => {
  if (acc[game.winner]) {
    acc[game.winner].wins = acc[game.winner].wins + 1 || 1;
  } else acc[game.winner] = { wins: 1, loses: 0};
  if(acc[game.loser]){
    acc[game.loser].loses = acc[game.loser]['loses'] + 1 || 1;
  } else acc[game.loser] = { wins: 0, loses: 1};
  return acc;
}, {});

const results = Object.keys(playerObjects).reduce((arr, key) => {
  const player = {
   name: key,
   wins: playerObjects[key].wins,
   loses: playerObjects[key].loses,
  };
  arr.push(player);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```